# How can I get a reference to the DOM elements for data bound from webapi?

Tags: angular

I am attempting to use Muuri in my app (https://github.com/haltu/muuri) for displaying data that I retrieve from a web API. If I understand it correctly, Muuri works using DOM items. If I hardcode some items in my markup, they work correctly. However, when I use `*ngFor` to bind items retrieved from a web API, they do not work correctly. I suspect that this is because they do not exist in the DOM.

I've created a sample project on Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xu5c3s

It looks like I need to call the Muuri `grid.add` method, but that method takes an array of DOM elements as a parameter. So I think there are two possible solutions, both of which evade me at the moment:

1. I need to find a way to get the DOM elements for the bound objects, and then pass them into `grid.add`
2. I need to dynamically create the DOM elements instead of using `ngFor` to display the items.

**How can I get Muuri to recognize my bound items?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular DOM rendering works differently. `Model => viewModel => View(DOM)`.
When we make any changes to model, we just update the viewModel, Angular internal DomRenderer(from @angular/platform-browser) during the every dirtyCheck, updates the native dom.

More info on mechanics of [DOM updates](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d).

More info on [Change Detection](https://blog.angularindepth.com/these-5-articles-will-make-you-an-angular-change-detection-expert-ed530d28930).

Since you are `*ngFor`, it manually creates the dom nodes and updates the viewModel, which is then picked up Angular and updated to the native dom.

SO I have called your `Muuri fn` inside `setTimeOut` with a delay of 100ms.

Here is the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvnc65)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! It did cross my mind that it might be a timing issue at one point, can't believe I didn't try a cheeky setTimeout :)

Comment: Actually I first tried with using `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`, after the api result is set to `this.users`. But it wasn't working. :D